# C++/CLI - Help with pin_ptr

Tags: managed-c++

I'm writing a wrapper app that uses some unmanaged functions and I'm using a lot of pin_ptr.

My question is, most of the time I use pin_ptr inside a method call, and the pin_ptr variable is declared also inside the method call. When the code goes our of the method, can I have any problem because it's no longer pinned? Should I move the declaration to a class scope?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only time you need to pin an object on the managed heap is when an unmanaged function or unmanaged code directly accesses the object in memory (such as through a pointer).  If when your method exits, nothing is currently accessing the object's memory, it can be unpinned (as long as you pin it again before directly accessing it the next time).